# Anexar arquivo em aplicação de email?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de emails e o front-end está sendo feito em VueJS/Quasar Framework e o servidor está sendo desenvolvido com o HapiJS.

Já consegui faze o envio de emails simples usando o [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) e estou listando eles na caixa de entrada da minha aplicação através do [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap).

Porém agora quero dar o próximo passo e quero adicionar anexos no email(PDF, .txt, imagens) e estou usando o `q-uploader` do Quasar para isso, porém só consegui fazer upload direto para um diretório dentro do servidor e eu queria mandar o arquivo como anexo do email.

Segue códigos e imagens...

`q-uploader` do quasar, onde o `:url` está definido para mandar os arquivos para o diretório no servidor

`<q-uploader slot="header" :url="url.url" color="light-blue-10" >Escolher Anexo</q-uploader>`

Imagens:

[image: Tela Principal]

[image: Tela de resposta]

[image: Tela de anexo]

Código do servidor:

```
server.route({
    path: '/enviar',
    method: 'post',
    config: {
        payload: {
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
            additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with', 'Accept', 'Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'f-None-Match', 'Accept-language']
        }
    },
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        let usuario = 'email@gmail.com';
        let senha = 'senha';
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: usuario,
                pass: senha
            }
        });


        let data = request.payload;
        if (data.file) {
            let nome = uuidv4();
            //let nome = data.file.hapi.filename;
            let path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + nome;
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
            file.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
            data.file.pipe(file);

        }


        let receiver = request.query.destinatario;
        let ass = request.query.assunto;
        let email = request.query.texto;
        let mailOptios = {
            from: usuario,
            to: receiver,
            subject: ass,
            text: email,
            attachments: [
                {
                    //filename: 'Arquivo de Teste.txt',
                    path: __dirname + '/uploads/' + data.file.filename
                },
            ]
        };

        console.log(mailOptios);
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptios, function (err, info) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log('Enviado! ' + info.response);
                return reply.response('Enviou')
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Como fazer upload do arquivo de anexo junto com o email??